# "shiver at the thought of" or shiver from the thought of"?

Tags: prepositions

Tell me please which preposition is correct to use in the following sentence.

> Kate was shivering **at**/**from** the thought of being fired for turning up late.

Answer (score 1):

**At** preposition is used to show the situation somebody/something is in

> The country is now at war.

So **at** preposition is more idiomatic.

> Kate was shivering **at** the thought of being fired for turning up late.